# I get a C2228 error while trying to create a color to change the background of a Windows::Form

Tags: forms, c++-cli

Here's my code.

```cpp
void Form1::dessin(int choice){
    switch(choice){
    case 0:
        Form1::BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveBorder;
        break;
    case 1:
        Color MyColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
        Form1::BackColor = MyColor;
        break;
    case 5:
        this->Ofck->Text = "textbruh";
        break;
    }
}
```

I receive 4 errors for this simple code :

```
Error   3   error C2228: left of '.FromArgb' must have class/struct/union   c:\Users\gabas\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain.cpp    27  1   Iwannatrain
Error   2   error C2275: 'System::Drawing::Color' : illegal use of this type as an expression   c:\Users\gabas\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain.cpp    27  1   Iwannatrain
Error   4   error C2360: initialization of 'MyColor' is skipped by 'case' label c:\Users\gabas\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain.cpp    30  1   Iwannatrain
Warning 1   warning C4832: token '.' is illegal after UDT 'System::Drawing::Color'  c:\Users\gabas\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain\Iwannatrain.cpp    27  1   Iwannatrain
```

I know this might be a novice issue, but I really can't wrap my head around this error.

Comment: Is this C++/CLI? Since native C++ doesn't have Windows forms support.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It is C++/CLI

Comment: @rMAszter Then tag it as such.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Done.

Comment: Too many syntax errors can confuse the dickens out of a compiler.  BackColor is an instance property, not static, so you must use `this->BackColor`.  FromArgb() is a static method, so now you must use `::`.  C++ doesn't permit variable declarations in case statements without `{}` to limit scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding what the error was (although I don't have the proper explanation).

The code here...

```cpp
Color MyColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```

should be written like this...

```cpp
Color MyColor = Color::FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```